# How to use a default value for locals in HAML?

Tags: html, ruby, forms, haml, default-value

I have a HAML template that I want to render and optionally provide a local variable to, here called post, so that it either uses the provided variable as the value of an element attribute, or falls back to an explicit default.

The code below shows what I mean, but it fails to run if `post` isn't provided. Is there a clean solution to this? I have quite a few of these fields, and I'd rather not have to keep duplicating them with `- if defined?` statements, which is the only other alternative I can think of.

```
%label
  Post title
  %input{:name  => "title",
         :value => (defined? post) ? post.title : ""} }
```

Comment: in an erb partial with an optional variable, I usually just say `post ||= nil`. Then you can do conditional logic, without hitting an undefined variable exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, turns out the real problem was that this is in Sinatra, which defines a `post` method to define handlers for HTTP posts, and the HAML renderer can see this.

If you provided a `post` variable to the renderer it hides it, so the template works fine, but otherwise `post` is actually a function, and so `defined?` is true, but clearly there's no `title` property.

Just changing the name of the variable makes everything work as I expected.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  I shoulda thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this doing this:

```
%input{:name => "title", :value => post ? post.title : ""}
```

You don't need to check with defined because `nil` is treated as false in the Ruby interpreter.  This excerpt from [Eloquent Ruby by Russ Olsen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321584104) describes it best:

> In Ruby, only `false` and `nil` are treated as `false`.  Ruby treats everything else--and I do mean everything--as `true`.

If this is a Rails app, a more eloquent solution would be to use the Rails `try` method:

```
%input{:name => "title", :value => post.try(:title)}
```

The `try` method invokes the method identified by the symbol that's passed in on the class unless the class itself is `nil`, in which case it will return `nil` (which haml will automatically convert to a blank string).  [Read more about the rails try method here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to deal with the case that some variable be nil, you can use the `try` method. For example:

```
%input{:name  => "title", :value => post.try(:title) } }
```

When post is nil, it just returns nil; otherwise post.title is returned.

**However**, if you want to provide explicit default values, then you should either write a helper (something like `default_if_nil`) or monkey-patch the `try` method to make it able to specify default values.

Comment: Just FYI, this wouldn't work in a sinatra app because it is a method that gets added to classes for `Rails`.  The method doesn't exist in Ruby or Sinatra.  See the bottom of my answer for more details about it.